# Odd behavior in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |Import-Csv |Export-Csv "C:\Somelocation\inbound.csv" -NoTypeInformation -append
```

I am trying to merge multiple csv files containing specific user information into one file so that the file can be processed by another routine which updates my active directory.

I am using Powershell Version 5.1.

The code worked twice without issue then stopped and started producing either blank files (no data at all not even headers) or started filling up with data that was not in either csv file to begin with

This is a sample of the wrong data

```
"showrepl_INFO","MyCityName","A machine name","DC=mydomain,DC=com",etc...
```

It repeats the above line several times.

Can someone please help me out? I have reviewed other similar questions on this site but none of those answers actually worked for me, except the line above which worked only temporarily. The csv files to be merged are identical when it comes to the amount of columns and the column names and order. So the first line of all the files after the first one needs to be ignored.

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: If all input *.csv files have the same column structure as well as any preexisting output file, there's no explanation for your symptom. Do all input files have the same structure? Also, unless you want to append to a preexisting output file, remove `-Append` from your `Export-Csv` call.

Comment: Yes, all the input files have the same structure. I am using Powershell version 5 - perhaps this is caused by an outdated version? I know powershell is at version 7 so I was wondering if that could be an issue.

Comment: It would be a major bug, and I cannot reproduce it, neither in Windows PowerShell nor in PowerShell (Core) 7.3.3.

Comment: Unless you can come up with a [mcve], I suspect no one will be able to help. In the process of constructing such an example, you may even discover the cause of the problem yourself. Again, note that you probably don't want the `-Append` switch.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I removed the 'append' as you are correct, it is not required. I swapped out the -Filter for -Path and included a full path name. This seems to have stabilized the process and I can consistently get the desired output now. I am not entirely sure why the -Filter worked for the first two runs then failed every run after that. The source and the destination files are not in the same directory. Perhaps this caused the issue?

Comment: With just `-Filter` and no `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` argument, the CSV files in the _current_ directory are picked up, so perhaps you ran from the wrong directory when you saw your problem. Indeed, the output file _should_  be in a _different_ directory, otherwise, if it already exists, it will become part of the input.

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\test*.csv" 
foreach($file in $files)
{
   $csv = Import-Csv -Path $file
   $table += $csv 
}
$table | export-Csv "filename"
```

Comment: This a more verbose, less efficient, syntactically broken reformulation of the code in the question. If the code were fixed, the only appreciable difference would be the absence of `-Append` from the `Export-Csv` call (which may indeed not be necessary). Of course, if that's what it comes down to, the verbose, inefficient reformulation is not only a distraction, but an example of how not to write code in PowerShell.

Comment: @mklement0 : My code is tested.  Posted code does not work according to OP.

Comment: The fix notwithstanding (I was looking at an earlier, broken version), my previous points stand: your code is an unnecessary distraction that showcases bad PowerShell habits.

Comment: @mklement0 : My code is good programming practices according to all my college professors.  Try to write code in one line is called Power Programming which is hard to document and even harder to understand and debug.  I learned "C Language" volume 1 the hard way by `K&R' which the samples were all written using Power Programming with little documentation and everything do with as few line as possible.  The second version had twice the number of pages because the examples were modified so the code was document and not done in one line.

Comment: It isn't the use of multiple lines that makes your code bad PowerShell code. Conversely, it's easy to spread a PowerShell pipeline across multiple lines (which is indeed advisable) - just end each line with `|`.